# Spring Sleuth X-Span-Export/spanExportable not displaying in log4j

Tags: log4j2, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Spring Sleuth with Log4j2 logger,

While to trying to print TraceId, SpanId & Span Exportable in logs, below pattern didn't print the Span Exportable flag,

```
%X{traceId},%X{spanId},%X{spanExportable}

%X{traceId},%X{spanId},%X{X-Span-Export}
```

While tried to analyse with `%X` - {spanId=d1457051eee5778d, traceId=d1457051eee5778d}

Answer (score 0):

As explained in Sleuth 2.0 to 3.0 migration guide [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.0-Migration-Guide)

> For performance reasons, we no longer set the following fields by
> default:
>
> - parentId
> - spanExportable

To enable that fields you should add following bean to your application:

```
@Bean 
CorrelationScopeCustomizer addSampled() {
  return b -> b.add(SingleCorrelationField.create(BaggageFields.SAMPLED));
}
```

And also you should use "sampled" field in your patterns nor "X-Span-Export" or "spanExportable".